# I want reducer to return undefined

Tags: redux

I have for example this a key in my redux store called `user`. When *logged in* it is an object `{ name: 'blah', foo:'bar' }`. Now when it is *NOT logged in* I want it to be `undefined`. However redux complains with something allong the lines of `Reducer "user" returned undefined to ignore an action return the previous state`. However I really want `undefined`. This is because throughout my app I have a destructure on user like this `let { user:{name, foo}={} } = this.props`. If it is undefined, then the default `{}` is taken so name and foo are undefined. HOWEVER to avoid the error I have set `user` to `null` and now I'm in a world of hurt because all my destructures (`let { user:{name, foo}={} } =`) are failing because when `null` the default value is no taken.

Is it ok if I returned undefined? Is something bad happening in redux?

Comment: You [can't return undefined from a reducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html#notes) in redux.  Can you use an empty object instead, i.e. `{}`, when the user is not logged in?

Comment: @MichaelPeyper - Darn, I really needed `undefined` because I do a check for `if (user) ` to determine if user is logged in too, in many places. Maybe in the redux.connect i'll have to convert null to undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `combineReducers` utility explicitly warns you when a reducer returns `undefined`.  This warning only happens in development.  So, if you can live with that warning in dev, go ahead and return `undefined`.